# SQL query which convert a reservation table to occupancy table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a hotel reservations table with three columns: arrival date, departure date, and number of guests. I would like to create another table with two columns: date and total guest who are present in the hotel in this date. Can you help me to produce query to accomplish this?

this is a simple reservation table:

| arrival_date | departure_date | guest_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 3 |

and this is the desired table:

| date | total_guest_number |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 5 |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 |

Comment: The date difference between arrival and departure is always one day ?

Comment: No, there are many reserves with more than one day staying in the hotels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `recursive cte` to accomplish this. Below is simply returning only dates with reservations. You could optionally add a calendar table to show ALL dates. That's up to you.

```
create table reservations (
  id integer, 
  arrival_date date, 
  departure_date date, 
  guest_number integer
  );
  
insert into reservations values 
(1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', 2), 
(2, '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', 3), 
(3, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-07', 4), 
(4, '2022-01-15', '2022-01-16', 1);
```

---

```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
   select id, arrival_date, departure_date, guest_number
   from reservations
   union all
   select id, arrival_date + interval 1 day, departure_date, guest_number
   from Date_Ranges
   where arrival_date < departure_date
  )
select 
 arrival_date as date, 
 sum(guest_number) as total_guest_number
from Date_Ranges 
group by arrival_date
order by arrival_date;
```

| date | total_guest_number |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 6 |
| 2022-01-02 | 9 |
| 2022-01-03 | 7 |
| 2022-01-04 | 4 |
| 2022-01-05 | 4 |
| 2022-01-06 | 4 |
| 2022-01-07 | 4 |
| 2022-01-15 | 1 |
| 2022-01-16 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibw94AP1k43mZrwaJDmsFm/0)

Answer (score 1):

If there always one day difference between arrival and departure :

```
select `date`, sum(guest_number) as total_guest_number
from (
  select arrival_date as `date`, guest_number
  from mytable
  union all
  select departure_date as `date`, guest_number
  from mytable
) as s
group by `date`;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pFZ_ABw2)

Comment: Even though the question is not clear , this isn't the right way to do it in my opinion. Consider another value `('2022-01-07', '2022-01-10', 15)` , in this case for each day between  2022-01-07 and '2022-01-10 there are 15 guests , see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mzu1DSGg) . My suggestion would be using a calendar table generated by the first arrival and latest departure date (my opinion)

Comment: I have already mentioned that My answer is valid only if the date difference between arrival and departure is one day ! Your suggestion to use a calendar table is correct